# I have a problem with video capturing in opencv, How to debug it?

Tags: python, video-capture, opencv

I'm working with opencv in python and ran into a problem (-215:AssertionFailed) for video capturing
how can I fix it ?.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.resize(frame, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)

    cv2.imshow("Frame",frame)

    ch = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if ch & 0xFF == ord('q'):
       break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Full line of bug**: cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-m9hy83n6\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:3929: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'

**And also it says the problem's from line 10**: cv2.resize(frame, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)

Comment: You are trying to resize your frame to (0,0) i.e. 0 width, 0 height?

Comment: No, (0,0) is size of the frame before changing to 0.5.

Comment: it seems that the frame image has something wrong (It might be None type dummy data). Could you print out the frame before resizing?

Comment: Yes Algopark, I printed it and it's none type. What should I do ?